# Send user to PayPal Guest Checkout

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I would like to use PayPal to allow my clients pay with credit or debit card, I already allow payments with PayPal,I know under the button of the login PayPal form, its a button who says "Pay with credit or debit card" but I would like send the user directly from the script to PayPal Guest Checkout.

I use PayPal SDK and this my code:

```
if($Payment_Type == 0)
{

if(!isset($Payment_Type))
{
    die();
}

$product = 'Reservation';
$price = $Total;
$shipping = 0.00;

$total = $price + $shipping;

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$item = new Item();
$item->setName($product)
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setPrice($price);

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems([$item]);

$details = new Details();
$details->setShipping($shipping)
    ->setSubtotal($price);

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setTotal($total)
    ->setDetails($details);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($itemList)
            ->setDescription('Service My Transfer In Cabo')
            ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();     
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(SITE_URL . '/pay.php?success=true)
    ->setCancelUrl(SITE_URL . '/pay.php?success=false);

$payment = new Payment();   
$payment->setIntent('sale')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

try {   $payment->create($paypal); }   
catch(Exception $e){ die($e); }

$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
header("Location: {$approvalUrl}");
}
elseif($Payment_Type == 2)
{
```

[I need this place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqbHA.jpg)

[Instead this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWYmp.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, guest checkout is not yet supported in the REST API.  You'll need to use Classic API Express Checkout if you'd like to force guest checkout.

You can use our [PayPal PHP class library](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) to get the classic calls setup quickly and easily.  Then you'll just need to setup the following parameters in your SetExpressCheckout request:

- SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
- LANDINGPAGE=Billing
- USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard

Comment: You are awesome. <3 you saved my life -_-

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$flowConfig = new \PayPal\Api\FlowConfig();
$flowConfig->setLandingPageType("Billing");
```

Set this flowConfig in the `webProfile`, and do:

`$webProfile->create($this->apiContext);`

add the ExperienceProfileId to the request of Create a Payment like below:

```
$payment->setIntent("sale")
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
    ->setExperienceProfileId(**********)
```

Refer to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32047084/212692

Comment: I've set this up... it showed a logo, but otherwise it still required PayPal account.